After updating Firestore, document view loses data
I have encountered quite interesting problem. I load data with .addSnapshotListener from Firestore and initial load is fine, even when I re-trigger different Firestore snapshot listener on .onReceive(of:) everything loads and updates. But when I trigger document update my Chart just does not have any data, like empty array have been passed to it. But when I dismiss the view and open it again, the data appears modified.
I had this same behavior dealing with other updates, but it was little bit more interesting, because I was using .setData([]: merge: true) and every thing else also just vanished. And then I removed merge parameter and the document updated but of course not the way I wanted by rewriting the whole document. For this case I just created new collection and handled the situation, but now I don't have that option. And I been trying to debug and find the problem, but nothing. With breakpoints till the last second the array has data, and then poof and gone. Any suggestions?
This is the function I use to updated the document:
func updateData(wallet: String, documentID: String, type: String, category: String, repeatTrigger: String, vendor: String, value: Double){
    var data: [String : Any] = [
        "category" : category,
        "repeat" : repeatTrigger,
        "type" : type,
        "value" : value
    ]
    
    if !vendor.isEmpty{
        data["vendor"] = vendor
    }
    referance
        .collection(userKey!)
        .document("Wallets")
        .collection(wallet)
        .document(documentID)
        .updateData(data) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error updating document: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Document edited succesfuly")
            }
        }
}

This is one of my functions that fetches the data from Firestore:
func fetchTransactionsForWeek(of date: Date, forWallet wallet: String, completion: @escaping ([ExpenseEntry], Date) -> Void) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startOfWeek = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: date))!
    let endOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: startOfWeek)!
    
    let startOfWeekTimestamp = Timestamp(date: startOfWeek)
    let endOfWeekTimestamp = Timestamp(date: endOfWeek)
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    
    reference
        .collection(userKey!)
        .document("Wallets")
        .collection(wallet)
        .whereField("date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startOfWeekTimestamp)
        .whereField("date", isLessThanOrEqualTo: endOfWeekTimestamp)
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching documents: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                    return
                }
                
                let transactions = documents.compactMap { document -> ExpenseEntry? in
                    let id = document.documentID
                    let data = document.data()
                    let entry = data["type"] as? String ?? ""
                    let value = data["value"] as? Double ?? 0.00
                    let category = data["category"] as? String ?? ""
                    let repetTrigger = data["repeat"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    let timestamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp
                    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp!.dateValue())
                    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
                        print("Unable to parse date: \(dateString)")
                        return nil
                    }
                    
                    let wallet = data["wallet"] as? String ?? ""
                    let vendor = data["vendor"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    return ExpenseEntry(id: id, entry: entry, value: value, category: category, repeatTarger: repetTrigger, date: date, wallet: wallet, vendor: vendor)
                }
                completion(transactions, date)
            }
        }
}

And both of these functions locate in different view models. In general the functionality is like updating the data and dismissing the view to parent, and the parent view should be updated.
Edit:
Just noticed that after update function the listener captures still the old values that wore in document. And yeah, the listener fires loads, but in the end just comes blanc, if needed I can provide with aggregation function, because I create empty data object for chart. But as I debugged it does not seem that there is the issue, only issue there I noticed was that I mentioned above, that receives old document values from load.

This DispatchQueue.main.async is generally not necessary within Firebase closures. Network calls are always done on a background thread and UI is done on main.
